# Error in http connection!!android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, json, ip

Basically, the only error I am getting when I try to request a http connection is,

```
Error in http connection !! android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

I am trying to connect to database in my Wamp server using an android emulator and this is part of the code I used,

```
   response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
   "http://152.226.152.96:89/MPSIP/jsontestscript.php",
   postParameters);
```

I also tried using localhost instead of my IP but I will get the exact same error.

I would like to know how I may establish a http connection with my wampserver. Am I missing out on a step or am I going about it all wrong.

If it helps, I used the guide from,

[Link to example used here](http://moinur-rahman.blogspot.sg/2012/02/connection-between-android-app-and.html)

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception?rq=1

Comment: And what does "network on main thread" tell you? What could it mean? And what happens if you search for that on the web?

Comment: Try this google search and click on the first link! https://www.google.co.il/search?q=android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException&aq=f&oq=android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException&aqs=chrome.0.57j61l2.144j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score -1):

This is probably because you are doing network operation on main/UI thread. Read about `AsyncTask` and `Thread`

Read [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).

P.S: Do some google search before posting questions on SO.